# Appengine JPA level 2 cache fails to persist

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

i am attempting to use the datanucleus jpa level 2 cache with appengine.

i am really unclear on how to configure for appengine.

i have the following

```
persistence.xml

<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2" value="true"/>
<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.type" value="javax.cache"/>
<property name="datanucleus.cache.level2.cacheName" value="xxxxx"/>
```

and the maven snippet

```
pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-jpa</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
    <artifactId>datanucleus-cache</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.10</version>            
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5</version>
  </dependecny>
```

Now the problem, when i persist a entity, it returns with a primary Key but it is not available from the either the datastore viewer or other queries.
I get this problem with in local dev, junit test or remote instance of appengine.

the code works fine as soon as the cache config is removed.

snipet of test

```
@Test
public void findById(){

    MerchantPromotion merchantPromotion1 = new MerchantPromotion();     

    em.persist(merchantPromotion1);

    MerchantPromotion  merchantPromotion = dao.findById( merchantPromotion1.getKey() );

    assertNotNull( merchantPromotion); <---- assert fails here

}
```

what is the issue?

thanks

-lp

Comment: You're using an old version of GAE JPA (v2.0.0 is their latest). A level 2 cache does not "persist". A level 2 cache caches things (that are persisted). Obviously looking at the log would tell you all about what is and isn't persisted, and what is and isn't cached.

Comment: thanks for the stating the difference between caching and persistence. i thought my question was very straight forward. Why adding level 2 cache does my entities not persist? datanucleus-jpa-1.1.5.jar is current for appengine 1.6.4.1, why is old if it part of the current distro?

Comment: v2.0.0-final is most recent. Your version uses ancient software from the start of AppEngine. I said look at the log, since that tells you what is happening; have you?

Comment: the upgrade to jpa 2.0.0 seems to have solved the issue. everything is persisting and caching nicely. thanks for your help.